# Jquery validation engine - How to use control IDs instead of names

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I've been using the JQuery Validation engine found here: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I'm using it within an Asp.net webforms website (not MVC). I have the form tag in the Masterpage and call the validation function from there.

```
$(function () {
                $("#form1").validationEngine('attach', { promptPosition: "topRight" });
            });
```

If the controls are on the MasterPage, the validators work fine, but if they are brought in from a content page, they aren't validated.

I looked around and saw that this is because .net renames the controls to avoid conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353664/1218621

So I put ClientIDMode="Static" in my MasterPage directive, but that only preserves the form control IDs, not the names. And this jquery validation engine calls items by their names.

I'm aware that I could write a script to rename my controls, but I've read that I won't be able to reference their properties on postback after that, and it seems like that wouldn't be best practice.

Since I can ensure what the control IDs will be by using ClientIDMode="Static", but I can't count on their name value not changing, is there a way to simply make the jquery validationengine work on control IDs instead of names?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the controls in your content pages as well. That is quite a nice client-side library; what are you using for server-side validation ? Have you tried using the `ajax[selector]` or `funccall[selector]` validation methods ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I wrote my own server-side validation to back it up, but haven't tried the ajax or funccall method yet.  I put the ClientIDMode="Static" on the controls too, but it's still not working.  View Source shows the name is still being changed in addition to the one I already set: <input name="ctl00$bodyPlaceHolder$txtFirstName" type="text" id="txtFirstName" class="form-control validate[required,maxSize[50]]" name="txtFirstName" />

Comment: ClientIDMode="Static" only sets the *ID* attribute; naming containers will still munge the *name* attribute. AFAIK there's no way around this. Do you have to use `name="txtFirstName"` Can it not select via ID ?